# LINQ to SQL with group by clause with aggregate function

Tags: c#, linq

I need equivalent LINQ to SQL query for the query written in access database. Below is the query in access database.

```
SELECT  Table1.ID, Table1.CODE, MIN (Table1.COST) 
FROM Table1 GROUP BY Table1.ID, Table1.CODE
```

In this query I get COST which is minimum to the given repeated CODE

Below query is giving error "Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access."

```
var ptQ = from i in
(from uh in ptTable
 select new
 {
     uh.ID, uh.CODE, uh.COST
 })

group i by new { i.ID, i.CODE }
into g

select new
{
    g.Key.ID, g.Key.CODE, g.Min(uh => uh.COST)
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the property name for the `Min` call:

```
select new {g.Key.ID, g.Key.CODE, MinimumCost = g.Min(uh=>uh.COST)};
```

The C# compiler will infer a name if the property value is a property or field access (as per ID and CODE), so the above is equivalent to:

```
select new { ID = g.Key.ID,
             CODE = g.Key.CODE,
             MinimumCost = g.Min(uh=>uh.COST) };
```

Personally I would specify the names everywhere if they're not idiomatic C# names otherwise:

```
select new { Id = g.Key.ID,
             Code = g.Key.CODE,
             MinimumCost = g.Min(uh=>uh.COST) };
```

Comment: I interpret the MS guideline as referring to *initialisms*, so `Id` is valid ;p

Comment: @Marc: I actually checked the guidelines and they *explicitly* call out `Id` and `Ok`. Other two-letter acronyms/abbreviations would be fully upper case.

Comment: Of course, MS follow this religiously too ;p (points vaguely at the `Min(...)` method...)

Comment: @Marc: The Min method is fine - it's three letters... (But "id" is sometimes ID and sometimes Id.)

Comment: the 3-letter rule is capitalisation - I was meaning the *abbreviation* guidance, which advises against shortening. In the v7 documentation the example was `GetWin` vs `GetWindow`. I guess it comes down to a subjective call on `Min` vs `Minimum` - meh, I'm not going to worry about it ;p

Comment: @Marc: Right, I'm with you. I think it's fine when an abbreviation is sufficiently well known :)

Comment: @Jon your reply helped me but gave rise to new problem (Exception), below is the post link
When I try to join two query which is of "Var" type I got below error msg.
IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).

Comment: @Khan: The queries aren't of type "var". "var" just performs type inference. Please post a *new* question with more details including the exception etc.

Comment: @jon this the link to question 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/a464ab3f-f1c8-4f8b-bec2-8cccdaf8227e

Comment: @Khan: I'm not going on to a different forum to answer the question. I suggest you ask it *here*, with more information (read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Comment: o.k asked here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027109/linq-to-sql-error-i
errorinfo-getdescription-failed

Comment: @Khan: I did say to add more information - what is DataContextServices? What are the two queries you've omitted? Please format the post, too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it what to call the last value in the anon-type (note that for *direct member access* members (`g.Key.ID` and `g.Key.CODE`) the name can be inferred (`ID` and `CODE` respectively):

```
select new {g.Key.ID, g.Key.CODE, MinCost = g.Min(uh=>uh.COST)};
```

You can also supply explicit names for the other members if you want:

```
select new {Id = g.Key.ID, Code = g.Key.CODE, MinCost = g.Min(uh=>uh.COST)};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it in one statement:

```
from i in Table1
group i by new { i.ID, i.CODE } into g
select new { g.Key.ID, g.Key.CODE, COST = g.Min(x => x.COST) }
```